# adding modules to my system

Tags: asp.net, dll, module

I'm designing an information system (in asp.net) in witch will be handling different modules once its done.
and i don't have enough time nor money to make all of the modules at once, so I've decided to do a few modules first and later on when i have time or money continue with the reset of them. 
Now the question is: is there a generic way to call a module from a list for example:I would create a directory with modules where i'm planning to drop the .dll of the modules, so when i make a new one i will put the new .dll there. On the other hand, i want to build something like a skeleton where i will generically call all the modules in the directory I've made via code, without having to re write the code of the skeleton whenever new modules are dropped into the directory. finally I've planned that each module should have three layers one for db accessing another one for logic and a the last one for interface drawing so each module should be independent of each other.
is it possible? how should i do this I've been looking but cant find anything yet.
is there a better way you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would definitely need to create common interfaces that modules implement and common data contracts. If you need to load dlls dynamically - it is possible but you would need to use reflection. Look here:

http://dranaxum.wordpress.com/2008/02/25/dynamic-load-net-dll-files-creating-a-plug-in-system-c/

Comment: thank u fenix this might help me i'll give it a try and tell u if it works for me :)